# Pandas dataframe, get the row number for a column meeting certain conditions

Tags: python, pandas

This is similar to a question I asked before but I needed to make some changes to my condition statement.

I have the below `output` that I make a dataframe from. I then check each row if `Status` rows are empty and if `comment` is not empty. The next thing I want to get is the row number of the Status col that meets those conditions:

```
output = [['table_name', 'schema_name', 'column_name', 'data_type', 'null?', 'default', 'kind', 'expression', 'comment', 'database_name', 'autoincrement', 'Status'], ['ACCOUNT', 'SO', '_LOAD_DATETIME', '{"type":"TIMESTAMP_LTZ","precision":0,"scale":9,"nullable":true}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', 'date and time when table was loaded', 'VICE_DEV'], ['ACCOUNT', 'SO', '_LOAD_FILENAME', '{"type":"TEXT","length":16777216,"byteLength":16777216,"nullable":true,"fixed":false}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', '', 'DEV'], ['ACCOUNT', 'SO', '_LOAD_FILE_ROW_NUMBER', '{"type":"TEXT","length":16777216,"byteLength":16777216,"nullable":true,"fixed":false}', 'TRUE', '', 'COLUMN', '', '', 'DEV']]

df = pd.DataFrame(output)

df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]


query_list = []


for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Status'] is None and row['comment'] is not None and row['comment'] != '':
        empty_status = df[df['Status'].isnull()].index.tolist()
```

I've tried with `empty_status` var above but I see:

```
empty_status_idx = [1, 2, 3]
```

when I would like it to be is below, because only the first row meets those conditions:

```
empty_status = [1]
```

because only the first row has a comment and has status empty or null

Comment: like this `df[df.Status.isnull() & df.comment.notnull() & (df.comment.str.len() > 0)].index.tolist()` with no `df.iterrows()`?

Comment: @Emma yes! this works perfectly I was hoping there would be another way since the var is in the if condition but I guess not?

Comment: glad it worked but I don't know what you mean here "since the var is in the if condition".